# Self adjusting random list

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I have a grid of 9 columns by 3 rows (so each column has 3 slots). A minimum of one slot in every column must be marked and no more than 3 can be marked. A mark is represented by a 1,2 or 3 digit.

There must always be 15 marked slots in total. To achieve this I tried the following:

```
var valueLeft = 15;
while (valueLeft > 0)
{
    var ranValue = utils.getRandomInt(1,3);
    console.log('slots remaining: ' + (valueLeft - ranValue));
    if (ranValue >= valueLeft)
    {
            ranValue = valueLeft;
    }
    valueList.push(ranValue);
    valueLeft -= ranValue;
}
console.log(valueList);
```

But this often gives me an array of numbers with less than 9 elements inside. I can see that my logic is flawed but I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out how I can get it to always give a set of 9 elements which all add up to 15.

For example what I might end up with is:
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]

When what I need for example is:
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2]
or
[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]

and so on.

Any advice appreciated. Feel free to flame me for my poor sense of logic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer shows a similar approach to many of those already posted, but I feel as though they're making it too complicated. It can be very straightforward:

```
function pad(list, size) {
    var total = list.length;
    while (total != size) {
        var i = utils.getRandomInt(0, 8);
        if (list[i] < 3) {
            list[i]++;
            total++;
        }
    }
    return list;
}

var valueList = pad(new Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 15);
```

You don't need a lot of cases. Just -- as many others have already said -- init the array with 1's. Then, simply add one to random elements (whose value isn't already 3) until the total is 15.

Comment: I appreciate the structure of this example and the explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

why don't you do this:

start off with an array that looks like this: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

then make a function that picks a random number between 0 and 8 6 times.

if the same number has been picked more than twice, skip it and pick a new one

then correlate those 6 numbers to the index of the array and add 1 for each time it picks that number.

```
var i; var valueList = new Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
var ranNum = utils.getRandomInt(0,8);
if(valueList[ranNum]<3) valueList[ranNum]+=1;
else i--;
}
```

just tested it, changed <=6 to <6 and it's working for me. Good luck!

Comment: Nice! so simple yet it does everything I want. Thanks Ryan and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Following logic should work. You should select a random value (within 1-3) such that choosing that would not lead us to not able to select a random value for further slots.

```
var gridLeft = 9
var valueLeft = 15
while(gridLeft>0) {
  var ranValue
  while(true) {
    ranValue = utils.getRandomInt(1,3);
    if (valueLeft-ranValue > 3*(gridLeft-1))
      continue;
    else if (valueLeft-ranValue < 1*(gridLeft-1))
      continue;
    else
      break;
  }

  valueList.push(ranValue);
  valueLeft -= ranValue;
  gridLeft -= 1
}
```